# dataframe compound calculation on aggregations

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

```
import pandas as pd

times = pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(['2014-07-4',
'2014-07-15','2014-08-25','2014-08-25','2014-09-10','2014-09-15']))

strategypercentage = [0.01, 0.02, -0.03, 0.04,0.5,-0.3]
df = pd.DataFrame({'Strategy': strategypercentage}, index=times)

##lambda x: ((1+x).cumprod()-1)


df.resample("1M").agg({'Strategy' : ['sum','prod']})
```

the dataframe includes dates, and daily percentage change, how i can calculate monthly percentage change compounded (looks like ((1+x).cumprod()-1)) - but how to implement with agg?
expected result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQHk3.png)

Comment: What is expected output? Because `sum` and `prod` return aggregate values and custom function not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need:

```
df['new'] = df.resample("1M")['Strategy'].apply(lambda x: ((1+x).cumprod()-1))
print (df)
            Strategy     new
2014-07-04      0.01  0.0100
2014-07-15      0.02  0.0302
2014-08-25     -0.03 -0.0300
2014-08-25      0.04  0.0088
2014-09-10      0.50  0.5000
2014-09-15     -0.30  0.0500
```

Comment: thanks, after it - i still need make agg!
~df['new'] = df.resample("1M")['Strategy'].apply(lambda x: ((1+x).cumprod()-1))

df.resample("1M").agg({'Strategy' :'sum','new': 'last'}) ~